# ORM for cloud spanner for nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Is there an implementation of ORM for cloud spanner in nodejs?

I can see that we can use the good old knex.js for mostly read operations, but that also seems more like a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go for unofficial and (probably) unsupported implementations, then there is this repository that adds support for Spanner to TypeORM: https://github.com/Rocketmakers/typeorm/tree/master/src/driver/spanner

It might be worth a try, and as it is open source, you have the possibility of adding features yourself. I have not tried it out myself, so I don't know how much it actually supports.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is support for any ORMs in NodeJS at the moment. There is only ORM support for [Hibernate](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-hibernate), [Spring Data](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/adding-spring) and [Django](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-django-cloud-spanner-database) (beta).

Comment: Okay. 
Thanks for your answer.

I can see that there aren't any official implementations for the ORM, but I'm curious about any unofficial implementation like open source etc?